Bootstrap 5 floating label overflows when inside grid
This markup contains floating selects inside a bootstrap grid:


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container w-50 mt-4">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-floating">
        <select class="form-select" id="a">
          <option value="" selected=""></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <label for="a">Foo Bar Baz</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto">
       <div class="form-floating">
         <select class="form-select" id="b">
           <option value="" selected=""></option>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
         </select>
         <label for="b">Spam Ham Eggs</label>      <!-- this overflows -->
       </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>



Notice how the second column has col-auto to minimise its width, but then the label overflows the column. I tried overflow-visible but that doesn't help - because the label is absolutely positioned.
Is there some way to fix this (without hardcoding a width)?

The select will size itself based on its contents. The contents are 1, 2, 3 which takes much less space than the floating label. The easiest way to fix that would be to set a min-width to the select element.

@MrUpsidown Agreed. But that's what I'm hoping to avoid (hardcoding some value).

A single JS line would fix that too (get the width of the label and apply it to the select).

Nah, I dislike those little js tweaks even more than hardcoding. :) Answer below is good.

What's causing the problem is that the label has position: absolute for the effect. Therefore, the width of the selection container has no relation to the width of the label. Even if both containers used col, the label would still overflow when the viewport is very narrow.
A hack would be to duplicate the label in a hidden span so that the width of the selection box won't be less than the width of the label text.
<span class="m-1 invisible">Spam Ham Eggs</span>


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container w-50 mt-4">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-floating">
        <select class="form-select" id="a">
          <option value="" selected=""></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <label for="a">Foo Bar Baz</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto">
       <div class="form-floating">
         <select class="form-select" id="b">
           <option value="" selected=""></option>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
         </select>
         <label for="b">Spam Ham Eggs</label>      <!-- this overflows -->
         <span class="m-1 invisible">Spam Ham Eggs</span>
       </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>



